# Non Superuser to Change the password of User Postgres

Tags: postgresql, authentication

How can non Super User Can reset the Password in Postgres DB?

```
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

Comment: you need to be an OS admin or a database admin.

Comment: A non-super-user can change their own password.  So if you are logged in as "user_name", then just do it.